# Can we get a flag history for chat's moderator attention flags?

Tags: feature-request, chat, flag-history, chat-flags

I checked my [chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1803692/vogel612) to see whether I can find something similar to the main-site flag-history for chat-flags, but didn't find anything.

I recently had the (dis)pleasure of regularly having to deal with a user, that has been deleted *multiple* times. Whenever they show up (with the same nick-name) again I have to flag them **again**.

I'd like to get an overview of how often I had to do that, and whether my flags were helpful for the moderators.

As such I propose the implementation of a flag-history as it is already in place for the main-site for chat-flags, that request moderator intervention.

To be completely clear I am not talking about the 10k user flags, which are acted on in a matter of sometimes seconds with instantly visible results, but about moderator attention flags from this menu:

[image: Moderator flagging interface]

Comment: Since this has not seen any activity, apart from the edit and bounty I assume this is not implemented yet. As such I have changed it from [tag:support] to [tag:feature-request]

Comment: Upvoted two years later, still missing this feature. If it will ever be implemented, I suggest to list every flag, not just the moderator level ones. When flagging questionable contents on some not-so-nice rooms, it isn't uncommon for me to get the flag killed of by some 10k+ user that has very weird ideas about "room culture". Since sometime I notice the bad content is still there only after days have passed I would find it useful to be able to check if I already flagged it (and who was the one that dismissed the flag....)